# Firebase.Xamarin is not compatible with monoandroid81

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to add firebase realtime database in my application but when I add a library for Firebase.Xamarin, it gives the error like

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>       Error     Package Firebase.Xamarin 0.3.6 is not compatible with monoandroid81 (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1). Package Firebase.Xamarin
>   0.3.6 supports: net (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0)          0

how can I solve this error, I tried to change the target version of application but it is not working. Please help me to solve this error.

[image]

Comment: Those are not official packages. Look for the ones published by Xamarin

Comment: i can not understand your answer. please explain in brief.

Comment: Use official Firebase packages published by Xamarin. Look for `by Xamarin` next to the package name. In your screenshot you are installing a package by some Ricardo.

Comment: ok i can understand.

Comment: Thank you it is working with Xamarin.Firebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the proper answer by adding the Xamarin.Firebase library instead of Firebase.Xamarin because Firebase.Xamarin is not official library.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to install `Firebase.Xamarin` which is published by an author named Ricardo. What you are probably looking for is the official packages published by Xamarin.

In this case they all start with `Xamarin.Firebase`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was with the cache of the nuget packages, for cleaning this cache, you have to go to "Tools>Options>Manage Nuget Packages> Clean Cache

Comment: Hope it helps!!

Answer (score -1):

I found the proper answer by adding the Xamarin.Firebase library instead of Firebase.Xamarin because Firebase.Xamarin is not official library.

[image]